# Blur effect on windows 8 store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, blur

i am trying to achieve a blur effect on an image in win8 store apps , when i developed for windows phone 8 i used [nokia imaging sdk](http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/imaging) to achieve blur , and when i tried to use it in win8 store app it gave me errors like for example i cant use writablebitmap.saveJpeg and other
and also i tried to use [direct2d](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.msdn.microsoft.com%2Fwindowsapps%2FDirect2D-basic-image-6b4b1a26&ei=9kj7U7X0K6Kl0QXzjYH4Dw&usg=AFQjCNH6JatSel3s-995v4fUzUcjyFTj1w&sig2=uMJFs2RHTpFhqc9il_pbaw&bvm=bv.73612305,d.bGE&cad=rja) but every sample is written in c++
How can I blur an image in a Windows Store App for Windows 8.0?

Comment: They don't like questions asking about tool recommendations on StackOverflow so I altered your question slightly to remove the request for recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct2D is probably the best solution here. If you'd rather avoid C++ (I don't blame you) - you could try using SharpDX for that, though you likely won't be able to escape reading some C++ oriented documentation to achieve that.
The easy way is to process the image on the CPU which you can do with WriteableBitmap and WriteableBitmapEx has [a method](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#branches/WBX_1.0_WinMD/Source/WriteableBitmapEx/WriteableBitmapFilterExtensions.cs) to help you here. You'd probably need to call something like `wb.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur3x3)`.
Jeremiah Morrill [wrote](http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/pixel-shaders-for-xaml-windows-runtime/) about his [XamlFx](https://xamlfx.codeplex.com/) Pixel Shaders library for XAML that you might try using as well. It's written in C++, but seems to be a WinRT component and so you can use it in a C# app.